# where to put business logic in Laravel5?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm a new to laravel. I am creating a web service based on Repository pattern, here is the link for your reference.

[Decoupling your code in Laravel using Repositiories and Services](http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services)

I know my question which depends on what my service is...
so please imagine some rich blog services. I think that I need not only to create many tables and functions, but also need complicated SQL(query builder).

I am writing complicated query(table ->join->join->where....) in "Model", then inject Model to Repository, after that bind it with Interface.

My question is that my process is correct or not. Is there any good way?